# Subtracting two Long values

Tags: java, subtraction

Why do I get error when I run the code below? How can I fix this? I want to `System.out.print(hi-hello);`

```
Long hello = 43;
Long hi = 3523;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print(hi-hello);
    }
}
```

Comment: does print take long parameter?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik i don't know

Comment: you should enable documentation feed if you have internet and if you are using eclipse. Then check warnings and errors

Comment: pretty sure OP has internet:)

Comment: @ZhongYu I felt like moron bwhahaaha.(maybe I am right now)

Comment: Your fields are non-static and the main method is static, you can't use non-static fields inside a static method. Also you defined the fields outside a class which is incorrect, you can't do that in Java. Thirdly you have to add the `L` or `l` suffix to the values assigned to the `Long` variables.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using the type `java.lang.Long` instead of the primitive type `long` - or is it just because you don't know the difference between `Long` and `long`? Use the primitive type `long` instead of the wrapper type `Long`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because **hi** and **low** are declared as **LONG** objects, they must be either declared as literal by adding the L at the end or use the Long class

```
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long hello = 43L;
        Long hi = 3523L;
        System.out.print(hi-hello);
     }
}
```

Comment: @Me123 This is not the correct answer. The L suffix is unnecessary on these small values.

Comment: I hurriedly voted down this answer down, but it is the right answer. Want to revert that. Any tips how?

Answer (score 2):

Your attribute declaration and init should be inside your class :

```
public class HelloWorld{
    Long hello = 43;
    Long hi = 3523;
```

Not out side for that you don't get correct result :

and your Long is not correct format it should be like this :

```
  Long hello = 43L;
  Long hi = 3523L;
```

And when you are calling your attribute in a static method then you should to make them static, so your program should look like this :

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  static Long hello = 43L;
  static Long hi = 3523L;
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.print(hi-hello);
  }
}
```

This will print:

```
3480
```

**NOTE**

Like @EJP said in the comment :

> When a number is too large to be represented by an int, it must be
>   explicitly declared as a long by adding an L:
>
> ```
> long n = 9876543210L;
> ```

Comment: I want to subtract hi and hello

Comment: i don't want to output "hi-hello"!

Comment: output 3480 basically

Comment: The L suffix is not necessary here.

Comment: @EJP i use what he said in the question so he use `Long` with a `L` not `long` ok check my answer now

Comment: The primitive type `int` is automatically promoted to a primitive `long` when it is assigned to a long variable if it is within the range of allowed `int` values, so you don't need the `L` or `l` suffix. For the wrapper class `Long` you have to indeed use the prefix `L` or `l` for all `int` values because Java have no way of promoting a primitive `int` value to a `Long`, it is a type mismatch.

Comment: so, did you find that my answer is wrong @Omoro or what?

Comment: Not at all, but was basically replying at @EJP.

Comment: what you think i should to do @Omoro haha

Answer (score -1):

**longs** does not use normal operators like **+** or **-**, instead, you need to use `Long.sum(long l1, l2)`.

I'm not sure if there's other ways to do it, but this is what I use.